# SQL Server 2000 Multiple IF Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I get a error when I try to use multiple IF statements. This is the error...

> "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   fnTNAccidentIndicator, Line 81
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'END'."

This is the structure of my code...

```
USE SS_TNRecords_Accident
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnTNAccidentIndicator
(
    @inAccidentNumber nvarchar(100),
    @inIndicatorMode int
)
RETURNS nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AlcoholInd nvarchar(1)
    DECLARE @DrugInd nvarchar(1)
    DECLARE @SpeedInd nvarchar(1)
    DECLARE @ReturnValue nvarchar(1)

    SET @AlcoholInd = '1'
    SET @DrugInd = '2'
    SET @SpeedInd = '3'
    SET @ReturnValue = 'N'

    IF (@inIndicatorMode = @AlcoholInd)
    BEGIN
        SELECT AccidentNumber, AlcoholTestResult FROM tblAccidentUnit
            WHERE AccidentNumber = @inAccidentNumber AND AlcoholTestResult NOT IN('00', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99')
        UNION
        SELECT AccidentNumber, AlcoholTestResult FROM tblAccidentOccupant
            WHERE AccidentNumber = @inAccidentNumber AND AlcoholTestResult NOT IN('00', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99')
        UNION
        SELECT AccidentNumber, AlcoholTestResult FROM tblAccidentNonMotorist
            WHERE AccidentNumber = @inAccidentNumber AND AlcoholTestResult NOT IN('00', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99')
        IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnValue = 'Y'
        END
    END

    IF (@inIndicatorMode = @DrugInd)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  a.AccidentNumber,'AccidentUnit' AS TableFound, c.PrimaryKey AS TableKeyValue
            FROM  tblAccident a INNER JOIN tblAccidentUnit b
                ON    a.AccidentNumber = b.AccidentNumber INNER JOIN tblAccidentUnitDrug c
                    ON  b.PrimaryKey = c.ForeignKey
                AND    a.AccidentNumber = '001' 
            WHERE c.DrugTestResult IN('02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '97', '98')     
            UNION       
            SELECT  a.AccidentNumber, 'AccidentOccupant' AS TableFound, c.PrimaryKey AS TableKeyValue
                FROM  tblAccident a INNER JOIN tblAccidentOccupant b
                    ON    a.AccidentNumber = b.AccidentNumber INNER JOIN tblAccidentOccupantDrug c
                        ON  b.PrimaryKey = c.ForeignKey
                AND    a.AccidentNumber = '001' 
            WHERE c.DrugTestResult IN('02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '97', '98')
            UNION
            SELECT  a.AccidentNumber, 'AccidentNonMotorist' AS TableFound, c.PrimaryKey AS TableKeyValue
                FROM  tblAccident a INNER JOIN tblAccidentNonMotorist b
                    ON    a.AccidentNumber = b.AccidentNumber INNER JOIN tblAccidentNonMotoristDrug c
                        ON  b.PrimaryKey = c.ForeignKey
                AND    a.AccidentNumber = '001' 
            WHERE c.DrugTestResult IN('02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '97', '98')     
        IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnValue = 'Y'
        END                 
    END

    IF (@inIndicatorMode = @SpeedInd)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  a.AccidentNumber,'AccidentUnit' AS TableFound, c.PrimaryKey AS TableKeyValue
        FROM  tblAccident a INNER JOIN tblAccidentUnit b
            ON    a.AccidentNumber = b.AccidentNumber INNER JOIN tblAccidentUnitDriverAction c
                ON  b.PrimaryKey = c.ForeignKey
                AND    a.AccidentNumber = '001' 
        WHERE c.DriverAction IN('28', '29')
        IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnValue = 'Y'
        END
    END

    Return @ReturnValue

END
GO
```

Comment: You can use the IN clause instead of multiple ORs. From your third query use [WHERE c.DrugTestResult IN('02', '03','04','05','06','07','08','97','98')]

Comment: I'm pretty confused by the edit history now. At one point you put up a version with DML statements and an empty `begin..end` that seems to have gone. Can you sort it out and format the code correctly using the `{}` icon not tags so we don't have to edit it.

Comment: @Martin - Sorry about that. I was making adjustments to the code and I wanted to post my code without all the select statements to narrow down the problem I was having. Guess I made it more confusing. I posted the code that I have in the IF statements this time.

Comment: I can't say, that the question is improved by editing it 8 times. It just got impossible to assign the answer to the different versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few issues I see here.

1. You have a parameter of type nvarchar without a size declared.  When this happens, SQL Server defaults to 1 character, which is probably not what you want.  I encourage you to specify the size.
2. Your function returns an nvarchar, but you did not declare the size.
3. You have declared local variables of type nvarchar without declaring the size.
4. You are assigning variables without using the set key word.  SET @ReturnValue = 'Y'

**EDIT**

1. You pass in @inIndicatorMode as an integer, but then you compare it to an nvarchar variable.  This will cause SQL Server to do a type conversion prior to the compare.  Type conversions are generally pretty fast, but it's best to avoid them when you can.
2. You appear to be hard coding values just for the purpose of comparisons.  Each declare and variable assignment will take a small amount of time to execute.  The only advantage I see to this method is self documenting code.  Instead of declaring variables, assigning variables, and then comparing those variables, I would suggest that you change the comparison to a hard coded value and then use comments in the code.

```
IF (@inIndicatorMode = 1) --Alcohol Indicator
 BEGIN
  --select statment   
  IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
  BEGIN
   SET @ReturnValue = 'Y'
  END
 END
```

1. It appears as though there are only 2 valid returns from this procedure, 'N' or 'Y'.  I would encourage you to change the return data type to a bit.  This allows you to write other code that treats the output of this function as a boolean instead of a string.
2. In your post, you show 3 blocks of code.  In the code you have a comment of "select statement".  I assume each select statement is different.  You also appear to be checking the @@RowCount afterwards, and if the row count is greater than 0, you set the output of the function to 'Y'.  Instead, I would encourage you to use the Exists function instead.  There is a slight performance gain when you use exists because it returns true as soon as SQL finds a single row that satisfies the query.  For example:

```
IF (@inIndicatorMode = 1) -- Alcohol Indicator
 BEGIN
  If Exists(-- Your select statement Here)
  BEGIN
   SET @ReturnValue = 'Y'
  END
 END
```

Comment: @G Mastros - Oh man! I didn't notice that I was passing in a int and then using nvarchar values to compare it to.

Comment: Make sure you use the last comment about the Exists function.  As your current code block shows, it will not compile because you cannot have a simple select statement in a function the way you do.  I mean, you can create a table variable and select in to it, but you cannot have a straight select like you have.  Also, I suggest you change the UNION to UNION ALL.  Union will filter out duplicates, which you don't care about here.  You're just looking for the presence of ANY matching row.

Answer (score 2):

Following your edit. You cannot have an empty `begin..end` block. It needs to contain something even if just a print statement or redundant assignment.

Comment: I think I would add that it appears the goal is to return a 'Y' in any case where there are results so you could potentially replace [SET @ReturnValue = 'Y'] with [RETURN 'Y']

Comment: @Suirtimed - That wouldn't work. You can only return integers with the `return` statement not character data.

Comment: You can return a string from a user defined function with the return statement.  Stored Procedures can only return an integer with the return statement.  Try it, you'll see.

Comment: @G Mastros - Absolutely correct. I didn't notice it wasn't a stored proc.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at your function, I don't think the problem is with the multiple if statements.  It looks like the problem is that you are doing @ReturnValue = 'Y' inside each if statement (forgetting SET).  It should be:

```
IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)     
BEGIN         
   SET @ReturnValue = 'Y'     
END
```

Also, it looks like you are doing the same thing inside of each if, you could combine the if statements into a single if with ORs.

```
IF (@inIndicatorMode = @AlcoholInd OR @inIndicatorMode = @DrugInd OR @inIndicatorMode = @SpeedInd) 
BEGIN     --select statment        
  IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)     
   BEGIN         
     SET @ReturnValue = 'Y'     
   END
END
```